# Suddenly can't open any port > 1000

Tags: ubuntu, port, mongodb

I'm quite a beginner with administration, and I've not had problems with my VPS before. But after having trouble with an upstart-bug, which I was able to solve, I had to reboot the system, and since then I cannot open any ports > 1000 any more, even with root.

I only need those for redis and mongodb, and only so my server can communicate with them locally (no outside listening). I get this error for mongodb, for example:

```
ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:99 Cannot assign requested address for socket: 127.0.0.1:27017
```

I haven't changed anything in the configs at all, merely installed the upstart patch. I don't even know how to find the actual problem.

Anyone can help me? I will provide additional logs or whatever if someone told me which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following :

- netstat -ap to see if something is listening on that port (27017)
- you could go with "ps aux | grep mongodb " if the apllication is already oppened .

If the above doesn't work , please let me know on which OS is the host so that I can troubleshoot this better (aka use specific OS commands ).

Regards,
Alex H

Comment: I've tried those. Mongo is not running and there's no other process hogging the port. Same with redis (port 6379). My OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Can you try to start Mongo , then restart apache ? IF that doesn't work look In apache error.log to see if there is any error (maybe a php initialize/compile error ? that apeared after the upgrade ?).

Comment: I cannot start mongo at all, as it will not open the port. What it does is start, then tries to open the port, fails, shuts down. Also, I have no apache installed/running. Only a node.js server.

Comment: Do you get more details in /var/log/mongodb/server1.log (or where you have mapped the logs for mongo ?

Comment: To test that you can't open ports over 1000 can you try to start mongodb with another port ? It should be something like ./mongod --port 391 , and with another port over 27001 ?

Comment: I can even start it manually when I am using `sudo mongod --port 27017`. So I am very sure by now it is a permission error. By default, it's started with the user `mongodb`. So how can I confirm it that this user can't open a connection?

Comment: Hello  to prove that this is a user permision :1.you could try to start it after logging with that user :"su mongodb" try to start it then see that you get the same error when you run it with root . 2. TO fix it you might want to edit /etc/init/mongodv.conf and you must ensure that the direcrtorys and files are writable by the user id which starts the service (mongodb)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2952/discussion-between-scan-and-alex-h)

Answer (score 0):

It might be appamour.. try to put it into complain mode

```
sudo aa-complain /usr/sbin/mongod
```

Then reload appamour

```
sudo invoke-rc.d apparmor reload
```

Then try to start mongo

Comment: Apparmor doesn't seem to be installed.

Comment: is somehow selinux installed? dpkg -l | grep selinux

Comment: There seems to be a `libselinux1` installed, version `2.0.98-1.1`. Nothing else matching.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to find out what port is open and listening by:

```
netstat -ltn
```

this will show all opened ports for listening (TCP ports only)
Now. If is there some port You want to close in order to open it on your own, You should enter this command (as superuser):

```
fuser -k <port>/tcp
```

replace  with number you want to close.
Try it and tell us how it is going.

Hope this help.

Comment: Fun is, I can open the servers all right as Root, but not via the `upstart` job.